# Fill area below a dashed line

Tags: flot

Right now I have the following data:

```
[{
  data : [[3, 4], [6, 5]],
  lines : { show : true, fill : true, steps : true },
  dashes: { show: true, lineWidth: 1 },
  color : 'red',
  label : 'Data series'
}]
```

If I change `lines.show` to false then the area below the line does not get filled. `dashes` does not have a `show` property.

Is it possible to **fill the area below a dotted line?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: Show the line and set its width to 0.

```
lines : { show : true, lineWidth : 0}
```